# InsecureRequestWarning + pytest

Tags: python, ssl, pytest

I still have the SSL warning on pytest summary.
`Python 2.7.5`
`requests==2.22.0`
`urllib3==1.25.3`
`pytest version 4.3.1`

This is the code:

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def test_x():
  response = requests.get("https:// ...",
                          verify=False)
  print response.text
```

The output **pytest mytest.py**:

```
....    
==================================================== warnings summary ====================================================
prova.py::test_x
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
    InsecureRequestWarning)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
========================================== 1 passed, 1 warnings in 0.30 seconds ==========================================
```

How can i remove the SSL warning from pytest?

Comment: You can _remove_ it only by turning the SSL cert verification back on. You can _hide_ it by applying the `pytest.mark.filterwarnings` marker to a test or configuring `filterwarnings` in the `pytest.ini`, see [Warnings Capture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html).

Comment: Nice, I added filterwarnings = ignore:.*Unverified HTTPS request.*
If you add this answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Restating the comment: You can *remove* it only by turning the SSL cert verification back on. You can, however, *hide* it (so the warning is still emitted, but not displayed in the warnings section):

#### selected tests

applying the pytest.mark.filterwarnings marker to a test, either by warning class:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning')
def test_example_com():
    requests.get('https://www.example.com', verify=False)
```

or by warning message:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore:Unverified HTTPS request is being made.*')
def test_example_com():
    requests.get('https://www.example.com', verify=False)
```

(the difference is between single or double colons in `ignore::` and `ignore:`).

#### complete test suite

Configure `filterwarnings` in the `pytest.ini`, also either by warning class:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning
```

or by warning message:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:Unverified HTTPS request is being made.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put this little code snippet out there for Django users- Add this to your imports:

```
import urllib3
```

Then add this to disable InsecureRequestWarning for all the tests on your file:

```
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for pytest, stated in the question itself.